# Cannot access docker Ruby on Rails image after running

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, dockerfile, docker-image

I'm new to docker and trying to follow some tutorials. 
I'm following this one: 
http://codingnudge.com/2017/03/17/tutorial-how-to-run-ruby-on-rails-on-docker-part-1/

and got stack at the end when running the docker image.

the issue as follows:

dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:2.3.1

#Install essential linux packages
RUN apt-get update -qq
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
build-essential \
npm \
libpq-dev \
nodejs \
postgresql-client \
&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

#Define where the application will live inside the image
ENV RAILS_ROOT /var/www/app

#Create application home. App server will need the pids dir
RUN mkdir -p $RAILS_ROOT/tmp/pids

#Set our working directory inside the image
WORKDIR $RAILS_ROOT

#Install bundler
RUN gem install bundler

#Use the Gemfiles as Docker cache markers. Always bundle before copying app src.

COPY Gemfile Gemfile

COPY Gemfile.lock Gemfile.lock

#Finish establishing our Ruby enviornment
RUN bundle install --deployment

#Copy the Rails application into place
COPY . .

RUN RAILS_ENV=production bin/rails assets:precompile
RUN ls -la
CMD rails server --port 3000
```

I'm running the following:

```
docker run -p 3001:3000 myapp
```

and when trying to access the app via

```
localhost:3001
```

It doesn't work and says that localhost did not send any data. 
Please help me out to understand what am I doing wrong here.

I'm running Mac OS for this.

thanks!

Comment: Did you build the Docker image?

Comment: It does look like it should work. If I shell into the image, I can start the server alright. But if I run this image with its CMD, webrick (my app's server) just doesn't start listening the port. This is too much debugging for me at the moment. Let's see what the morning brings. :)

Comment: @gasc yes the docker image is build

Comment: try `docker ps` (or `docker ps -a` if it crashed) to find the container ID, then `docker logs <container ID>` to see the server logs ... maybe it contains something useful.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev thats the point, in this tutorial they have the Puma server to run the app on, but for some reason it just refuse to listen to the given port. thanks for the assistance!

Comment: @gatoatigrado The container is up and running, last logs are just about the booting of the image. nothing looks wrong there.

Comment: These instructions in the article are dangerous, because they copy the Rails `bin` commands into the container. The path in the shebang for the binaries may not be correct for the image. However it may not be the problem here, just a side note.

Comment: Please add the output of this command to the text in your question: `head -n 1 bin/*`

Comment: On my test image Puma is listening only to localhost. This won't work with port forwarding.

Comment: @Casper regarding the copy part, what is suggested to do instead of copying? to do it in the better way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you supply the `--port` argument to `rails` Puma will only listen to the local interface. **Without** `--port` it will listen to all interfaces.

Therefore to force Puma to listen to all interfaces **with** `--port` you have to explicitly tell it to do that:

```
CMD rails server -b 0.0.0.0 --port 3000
```

This should allow the docker port forwarding to work properly.

Comment: in this case if I'm going to test this on AWS - linux server which has docker installed on it it should work as well, right? thanks again!

Comment: Yes. It should be no problem. You can leave the copy part. Should work fine for AWS. In most cases it should be ok.